# Чи правильно казати "домосід"?

Tags: етимологія, росіянізм

Зрідка, але зустрічається в ЗМІ слово "домосід", як на мене, схоже на бездумну кальку з російської мови.

Приклад вживання [тут](https://24tv.ua/irina_sheyk_nazvala_sebe_domosidom_i_ziznalasya_shho_priymaye_vannu_trichi_na_den_n1004702).

Утім, корені слова типово українські, та й колись чула, що для нашої мови характерне творення слів із усіченою основою, тому формально до домосіда питань не має виникати.

На думки наводить словникова стаття з [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/domosid), де приклади взяті з текстів радянських часів. Чимало росіянізмів тоді було не тільки в художній літературі, а й у самому словнику.

Слово домосід уживано не так вже й часто. Чи маємо яке інше слово із тим-таки значеням, якийсь цікавий синонім, може навіть образний? Натрапила було на кикимору, але мені здається, це більше про відразливу зовнішність, та й конотація виразно негативна, тому шукаю далі.

Comment: виправив "СМІ" на "ЗМІ", бо схоже на кальку)

Answer (score 5):

В СУМ-20 також є слово "домосід", проте там вже є інші, ніж в СУМ-11, значення та приклади вживання цього слова. Також слід відмітити, що слово ***"домосід"*** має позначку *розмовне* та подається посилання на інше слово (більш "головне", літературне) у словнику: ***"домувальник"***.

> ***[ДОМОСІД](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23860&page=803)***  *а, ч., розм.* Те саме, що домува́льник. *Ти говориш –
>   пожив би дома... Ну який з мене домосід?* (П. Дорошко); *Мої батько й
>   мати не любили світського життя і виїжджали тільки в крайніх випадках.
>   Вони були домосіди* (з мемуарної літ.);  Образно. *Коли настає зима,
>   бобри стають справжніми домосідами, адже вони зовсім не виходять зі
>   своїх темних нір, що складаються з мулу і дерева* (із журн.).
>
> ***[ДОМУВАЛЬНИК](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=157388&page=804)*** а, ч. Той, хто сидить удома, проводить час удома.
>   *Вони ще не звикли до таборових умов, а тому й думки їхні весь час линуть .. до своїх домівок і .. Усі вони за своєю вдачею
>   домувальники...* (Б. Антоненко-Давидович); *Цей архітектор жив як
>   каталонець: домувальник, із погляду загального світогляду, людина
>   досить вузька й містечкова, хоча, звичайно, був у курсі сучасної
>   світової культури* (із журн.).

Зі сторінки синонімів слова "домувальник" у ["Словниках України on-line" від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (також [продубльованої на uk.WorldwideDictionary.org](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B4)):

> ДОМУВА́ЛЬНИК (той, хто любить проводити час удома), ДОМОСІ́Д,
>   ДОМОСИ́ДА розм., заст., ХА́ТНИК розм., СИ́ДЕНЬ зневажл., ПІЧКУ́Р
>   зневажл., ПІЧКУ́РНИК зневажл., ДОМОНТА́Р заст., ДОМА́Р заст., СИДУ́Н
>   заст., ДОМОТУ́Р заст. *Ти говориш - пожив би дома... Ну який з мене
>   домосід?*(П. Дорошко); *Оце ще сидень, і між люде ніколи не вийде*
>   (Словник Б. Грінченка); - *Якого біса мені тут сидіти! - здивувався
>   Бульба.. - Щоб я став гречкосієм, пічкуром* (О. Довженко); -
>   *Реєстровці життям своїм жертвують, а якийсь пічкурник хутірський
>   лежить і живіт свій гріє* (І. Ле); *Хай товариство сміється з мене, що
>   я отаманства відбіг, що я домонтар, бабій* (Ганна Барвінок).